# Xcode Performance Test always reports "updated baseline value"

Tags: xctest

I have set up a performance test but every time it is executed it never fails no matter the fail criteria. Upon inspecting Xcode Report Navigator I notice it always says "Result: Updated Baseline Value". I have the code in version control and don't actually see a file being updated. Why is the test never failing regardless of what max standard deviation I use or baseline value I accept?

[image: Xcode]